# How to add a column based on values of columns indicated by another column in a tibble in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

In the example below, I would like to add column 'value' based on the values of column 'variable' (i.e., 1 and 20).

```
toy_data <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~x, ~y, ~variable,
    1,  2,  "x",
    10, 20, "y"
  )
```

Like this:

| x | y | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | x | 1 |
| 10 | 20 | y | 20 |

However, none of the below works:

```
toy_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    value = get(variable)
  )

toy_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    value = mget(variable)
  )

toy_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    value = mget(variable, inherits = TRUE)
  )

toy_data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    value = !!variable
  )
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You could reshape the data into a long format (like `pivot_longer(toy_data, -variable)`) and do a self-join...that might be a little convoluted for a small case like this but should scale well to a more complex dataset

Comment: If you have only two levels for `variable`, you can do: `toy_data %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(variable == "x",
                        {x},
                        {y}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few options that should scale well.

First is a base option that works along both the `variable` column and its index. (I made a copy of the data frame just so I had the original intact for more programming.)

```r
library(dplyr)

toy2 <- toy_data
toy2$value <- mapply(function(v, i) toy_data[[v]][i], toy_data$variable, seq_along(toy_data$variable))
toy2
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>       x     y variable value
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     2 x            1
#> 2    10    20 y           20
```

Second uses `purrr::imap_dbl` to iterate along the variable and its index and return a double.

```
toy_data %>%
  mutate(value = purrr::imap_dbl(variable, function(v, i) toy_data[[v]][i]))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>       x     y variable value
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     2 x            1
#> 2    10    20 y           20
```

Third is least straightforward, but what I'd most likely use personally, maybe just because it's a process that fits many of my workflows. Pivotting makes a long version of the data, letting you see both values of `variable` and corresponding values of `x` and `y`, which you can then filter for where those 2 columns match. Then self-join back to the data frame.

```
inner_join(
  toy_data,
  toy_data %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -variable, values_to = "value") %>%
    filter(variable == name),
  by = "variable"
) %>%
  select(-name)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>       x     y variable value
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     2 x            1
#> 2    10    20 y           20
```

**Edit:** @jpiversen rightly points out that the self-join won't work if `variable` has duplicates—in that case, add a row number to the data and use that as an additional joining column. Here I first add an additional observation to illustrate.

```
toy3 <- toy_data %>%
  add_row(x = 5, y = 4, variable = "x") %>%
  tibble::rowid_to_column()
inner_join(
  toy3,
  toy3 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(-rowid, -variable), values_to = "value") %>%
    filter(variable == name),
  by = c("rowid", "variable")
) %>%
  select(-name, -rowid)
```

Comment: Ah the `imap_dbl()` solution is one I was messing with it. That can be shortened to `purrr::imap_dbl(variable, ~ toy_data[[.x]][.y])` if one desired.

Comment: Just a heads up: the `inner_join()` method doesn't work if you have a variable column with duplicated entries - e.g. `c("x", "x", "y")`.

Comment: @jpiversen good catch, thanks! I'll try out numbering rows

Comment: @Adam yeah in practice I often use purrr's shorthands, but sometimes like to write the function out explicitly, especially when I'm working with indices

Answer (score 1):

If you know which variables you have in the dataframe in advance: use simple logic like `ifelse()` or `dplyr::case_when()` to choose between them.

If not: use functional programming. Under is an example:

```r
library(dplyr)

f <- function(data, variable_col) {
  
  data[[variable_col]] %>% 
    purrr::imap_dbl(~ data[[.y, .x]])
  
}

toy_data$value <- f(toy_data, "variable")
```